# Cesaro sum of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, cesaro-summable

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges in the regular term but is Cesaro summable

> Prove $a_n/n\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$

We used the definition of the Cesaro sum and obtained:

$\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{n=0}^{N}S_n$=$\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N+1}\left (  \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}S_n+\sum_{k=0}^{N}a_k\right )$=$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{S_n}{N+1}$$+\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{a_k}{N+1}$=$L$

but from here we're kind of stuck

*($S_n$ is the partial sums of $a_n$)

Comment: Since  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ is Cearo summable then the the serie $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{S_n}{N+1}$ is summable and so is $\sum{n=0}^{N}\frak{a_k}{N+1}$ is convergent so its general term has to approach to zero.

Comment: I don't understand the notations but I assume you mean $\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{a_k}{N+1}$. However I'm not sure how to obtain from that that $a_n/n$ tends to 0 since $a_n/n$ is not the general term of the series